# Progressive Linear functions

Tags: calculus, functions

I have a problem and I'm not sure how to calculate it or write it.
It uses Linear functon as:

> y = am + b

So the problem is that evrey time the unknown-m increases by 1,
The unknown-a will add to his amount +5.

Answer (score 0):

The function you end up with is not linear anymore, since $a$ is a (non-constant) function of $m$.

A function $a(m)$ that would agree with your description is $a(m) = 5m$.

The full expression would then become $y=5m^2+b$, which is a second-order function.

Comment: Could it be like y = a(5m2) + b ?